# List of running java application?

Tags: java, powershell

I want to find out what application associates with a port. But Get-Process(Powershell) command only show java.exe.

I need a detail of which java application. Using jps.exe is not possible for me since there is only JRE(not JDK) in my server.

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: This is off-topic - voted to close / migrate to Superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web page tells you how to get the command line arguments for a process using Powershell:

- http://mohundro.com/blog/2010/02/05/quickly-get-the-command-line-arguments-from-processes-with-powershell/

Comment: Wow! This is really what I need. I've stucked at this for a whole day. You're great!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can run 
`netstat -ano` to output the TCP/UDP connections and the PIDs associated with those connections.

Sample output of netstat -ano:

```
Proto   Local address   Foreign address State       PID
TCP         0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:0      LISTENING    460
```

Source:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980

Linux also has a `netstat` command.  `-p` will give you the process ids on linux.
http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: Thanks. But the PID associate with the connections is from java.exe . That doesn't answer my question of "which java application"

Answer (score 0):

You can use jconsole.exe to figure out which pid is associated to a java.exe. I'm not sure if it comes with the standard jre or if you need a jdk, but it is in the java bin folder.